# IntelliJ - Anti aliased fonts (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

What is the way to make IntelliJ fonts use Ubuntu fonts, my OS fonts are all anti-aliased however when I fire up IntelliJ the fonts does not look good.

Here is a screenshot of my IntelliJ using Oracle JDK:

[image]

I have already added these in the **idea.vmoptions**:

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
-Dswing.aatext=true
-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the font (or even seeing what's available) in the Settings window (`File > Settings`) under `Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font`?

Comment: What should I set on that? There is no option to set anti-aliased on/off there

Comment: Ah, I thought you were looking to set it to a specific font. There's an AA checkbox option under `Editor > Appearance`, although it was already checked by default for me.

Comment: Yes it is checked, I think my issue was with the font, my IntelliJ font is just not appealing :-/

Comment: And I believe the anti-aliased did not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's about the extent of my knowledge on fonts in IntelliJ.

Comment: The solution is install JDK from **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the moment I am using Intellij on Ubuntu with Xfce 4. The fonts in the editor are much nicer than under Unity.

Also I am using the dark UI - again much nicer that light with the same settings.

Check that you have this settings in your idea(64).vmoptions

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

(if it doesn't help, or is even worse with this settings try different values from http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering)

Also, I don't have this option so you could try to remove it.

```
 -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true
```